# Ethernet/Wirless does not work on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

I recently got a new  PC (specs will be shown below). Installation gave me no problem except Ubuntu can not connect to the internet. By the way i am very new to linux.

```
$ lspci -knn |grep -EA2 'Eth|net' output:

0e:00.0 ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros device [1969:e0a1] (rev10)
subsystem: Gigabyte technology Co. , Ltd Device [1458:e000]
0f:00.0 ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros device [1969:e0a1 (rev10)
subsystem: Gigabyte technology Co. , Ltd Device [1458:e000]
10.00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: intel corporation device [8086:1578] (rev 03)
```

I have 2 ethernet ports : `Qualcomm Atheros killer E2400`
And I have a wifi card: `Killer Wireless-AC 1535`

I do not have any internet access on my desktop.

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte z170x Gaming G1
- GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 980 TI
- RAM: 16GB Corsair DDR 4 (2x8GB)
- SSD: Samsung M.2
- HDD: Western Digital  TB
- SPS: Corsair 1000i
- CPU: Skylake i7-6700K (4GHz quad core)
- CPU Cooler: Cooler master

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: post was edited as instructed

Comment: you mean just type :  sudo ifup in terminal?

Comment: Check out trouble shooting wifi https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo

Comment: one issue i encountered with the given link is that it directs me to the link below which i believe i need internet inorder to install trusty back ports and my pc does not have that. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Atheros

Comment: I also get unable to install package amarok

Comment: Also i can not run the command that checks to see if "ath5k" is blacklisted. beacuse rep is not installed and i can not install it (NO INTERNET)

Comment: in total i tried that guide and it did not work. i still prefer to get my Ethernet working.

Comment: One other thing that looks wierd to me is that when i ran the command sudo lshw -c network all the networks have UNCLAIMED mark infront of them

Comment: Have you tried restarting the ethernet interfaces while Ethernet is pluged in? "sudo ifdown eth0" "sudo ifup eth0"

Comment: when i try sudo ifup eth0 i get: ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0 and when i try sudo ifdown eth0 i get: ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Comment: ANY ONE HAS ANY OTHER IDEAS?

Answer (score 0):

I have an alienware 17, brand new. Same problem, no ethernet, same card, the 1535. I noticed this bug report:

bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184

I tried the comment #290, and reinstalled (by simply copying new files into the firmware directory) the firmware for the ath10x section. OP, does this fix work for you? This worked for others, but seems they are using the 1525 card. It did not work for me.

checking the logs, I noticed that there may be a collision between the bluetooth drivers and this driver. I am going to try to "blacklist" the bluetooth, or get it to load after. If anyone can help out there how to do this I would really appreciate it.

I will post when I figure that out.

Comment: I heard if you do ubuntu 15.04 (unstable realese) this will be fixed (i have not tried it yet) exact quote: "The kernel modules in 14.04 don't support the killer NIC. You need to upgrade to 15.04"

Comment: I tried the solution above and it did not work

Comment: ok, there is also this:        http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux      BUT it seems like it will ONLY work with the 4.xx.xx kernel. I thought about dialing forward my kernel, but, found people online who said that their NVIDIA drivers did not work. I  purchased a PANDA brand USB wireless dongle, uh, thingy and that works no problem. I dont like this stupid stick hanging out of my alienware, but, until everyone goes to 4.xx.xx kernel I think I am stuck.